# TypeScript: properly typed function to sum multi-dimensional array column values

Tags: typescript, typescript-typings, typescript-generics

Let's say I have the following `sum()` method to sum multi-dimensional array column values:

```
export class MathUtils {
    static sum(values: Record<string, unknown>[], key: string): number {
        return values.reduce((acc, cur) => acc + cur[key], 0);
    }
}
```

Now I would like to use TypeScript to enforce the following:

- `key` parameter should always be one of the `values[index]` object keys
- `values[index][key]` has to be of type `number`. It should also allow other properties to be typed differently.

How could I do that?

Comment: `static sum<K>(values: Record<K, number>[], key: K): number` use a generic type

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Solution**:

```
function sum<O extends Record<T, number>, T extends keyof O>(values: O[], key: T): number {
    return values.reduce((acc, cur) => acc + cur[key], 0);
}
```

1. Makes sure that the property name is correct.
2. Checks if selected property's type is number. Allows other properties to be typed differently.

**Tests:**

```
interface ChartItem {
    name: string;
    value: number;
}

const items: ChartItem[] = [{
    name: 'Series #1',
    value: 10
}, {
    name: 'Series #2',
    value: 5
}];

// Works as expected
let total = sum(items, 'value');
// Error: 'foo' doesn't exist in ChartItem
total = sum(items, 'foo');
// Error: Types of property 'name' are incompatible
total = sum(items, 'name');
```

Answer (score 0):

1. key parameter should always be one of the values[index] object keys

You can achieve this by using generic types.

```
static sum<K>(values: Record<K, unknown>[], key: K): number {
```

2. values[index][key] has to be of type number.

You can specify the type of the value by the second type parameter of the `Record`

```
static sum<K>(values: Record<K, number>[], key: K): number {
```

Comment: 1) I don't want to manually specify the property names, it should get them automatically from the object type, sth like `T extends keyof O`.


2) This will not allow me to pass objects where some of the property values are not numbers. I want to make sure that only the property with the specified key is number.